# kendo drop down list does not autoselect the initial value(--select--)inserted at run time in update method

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo grid with pop up editing mode and editor template.
The editor template consists of a kendo drop down list which is bind through the database and i have inserted the optional label value ie "--select--" at run time in controller which works good for add method but for update method it is not autoselecting the "--select value--" and on click value is selected at second hit. Please help if anyone has any solution to this.

Edited: Please find the below code snippet for my drop down list.

```html
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("Type")
          .DataTextField("Value")
          .DataValueField("TypeID")
          .DataSource(source => 
               {
                   source.Read(read => { read.Action("Action Name", "Controller name"); }); 
               }) 
             )
```

// Controller code for binding drop down list

```html
 [AllowAnonymous]
          public ActionResult GetTypes()
          {
//my code to get list of types from db in object "Type"
Type.Insert(0, new TypeModel() { Value = "--Select--", TypeID = Guid.Empty });
              return Json(Type, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }
```

Comment: Please show us a working jsfiddle/jsbin example

Comment: Really sorry for that. I can't disclose whole code. The Problem is that how to get a value auto selected in drop down at page load.

Comment: what version of Kendo UI are you using?

Comment: You should use either an `optionLabel` or turn `autoBind` on in dropDownList options

Comment: @Dion The version is 2015.1.318

Comment: @mshaaban I have tried both..but not succeded.

Comment: What about pasting only your dropDownList configurations alongside the input data

Comment: Please see the post. I have edited it with a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in comment section, Kendo UI 2015 Q1 comes with some new features for dropdown family widget e.g autocomplete, dropdown, multiselect, etc and it also has some bug on it. 
So its not your fault that the dropdown won't recognize on the first select event.
The developer had fixed this issue and release a service pack for this, therefore all you have to do is upgrade or downgrade your Kendo UI version..

See this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ufAKO/27) where the grid's filter doesn't work for the first time selection
and if you downgrade its version or upgrade it, it will works fine like in this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/areFi)

[Kendo UI 2015 Q1 SP1 Release History](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/q1-2015-sp1), you will see on DropDown section that the issue have been fixed..

Comment: Gr8..Thanks for your help. I'll try this for sure and will post here the result.

Comment: I have another problem also. Can you please guide me on how to get the value autofilled in the drop down list from the database when working on update method which i have saved at the time of adding a  new record. I hope i am clear with my question.

Comment: which side do you mean, in client side or server side?
Instead telerik had provide a demo for us, you could refer to that demo if you found a difficulty.. here is the [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup)

Comment: If still have trouble you could post another question and give us some code that you have tried so far..